# Multinomial Coefficients Confusion

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, multinomial-coefficients

As far as I know for binomial coefficients, we can express one as either $\binom {n} {k}$ or $\binom {n} {k,\ n-k}$. If I'm not wrong they both mean the same thing: $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

What about multinomial coefficients? If I have an expression $\binom {n} {i,\ j}$, is it the same as $\binom {n} {i,\ j,\ n-i-j}$? Which one of the two is $\frac{n!}{i!j!n-i-j!}$ and which one's $\frac{n!}{i!j!}$? I'm confused.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to rely on the author of whatever text you are reading to explain the notation used there.  While $\binom{n}{k}$ is standard enough as a binomial coefficient to be used with little risk of confusion, a paper that expresses multinomial coefficients in different notations should provide an introduction defining each of them for the Reader.

Comment: If $i + j = n$, then $n - i - j = 0$.  Thus, $(n - i - j)! = 0! = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a more intuitive understanding by considering dividing people into labelled groups.

If $10$ people are to be divided into two labelled groups $A$ and $B$ of, say, $7$ and $3$,

we can use the binomial coefficient to write $\binom{10}7$ or the multinomial coefficient to write $\binom{10}{7,3}$

If we are to divide them into *three* groups of $5$, $3$, and $2$,
we can write  $\binom{10}{5,3}$ or $\binom{10}{5,3,2}$ because the last group gets formed automatically with the residue.

*The point is that the last part can always be left out of the expression,*
and conventionally it is left out when there are two groups, but is left to taste when more than two groups are there.

In $\binom{n}{i,j} \equiv \binom{n}{i,j,n-i-j}$

the $RHS$ is the full expression for $3$ groups with the last group having $0$ members,
and the LHS is the abridged form for the same grouping.

Comment: Just to clarify - so $\binom {n} {i,\ j}$ can be either a binomial combination where $i+j=n$ or a trinomial combination with $i, j$, and $k = n-i-j$ (if $i+j≠n$)?

Comment: Yes, the tendency to abridge it is more when (here) $k = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As hardmath, I also recommend to read what is stated as definition. Anyway the following can be said (I cite [Wikipedia:Multinomial Threorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem)):

> For any positive integer m and any nonnegative integer n, the multinomial formula tells us how a sum with m terms expands when raised to an arbitrary power n:
>   $$
>     (x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m)^n = \sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n} {n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} \prod_{1\le t\le m}x_{t}^{k_{t}}\,,
> $$
>   where
>   $
>     {n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} = \frac{n!}{k_1!\, k_2! \cdots k_m!}
> $
>   is a multinomial coefficient.

So $\binom {n} {i,\ j}$, is **not** it the same as $\binom {n} {i,\ j,\ n-i-j}$, since for the first $j=n-i$ holds.

An example: You get $\binom{10}{2,3,5}$, but $\binom{10}{2,3}$ doesn't make sense...

Comment: We can expand $\binom{10}{2,3,5}$ to $\binom{10}2\binom83\binom55$ which evaluates to the same as $\binom{10}2\binom83$

Comment: @trueblueanil maybe it's a matter of taste to leave out the last addend...

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. I have changed "choice" to taste" in my answer.